# Add custom sort by options for magento 2 catalog

Tags: orders, sort, sortby

In magento 1, for my catalog Product List, in Toolbar.php already i added sorting class and in my catalog page - there was an option to sort products about these attributes:

```
<?php

    class Product_List_Toolbar extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
    {
        public function getAvailableOrders()
        {
            return [
                'relevance' => 'Relevance',
                'name_asc' => 'Title: A-Z',
                'name_desc' => 'Title: Z-A',
                'price_asc' => 'Price: Low to High',
                'price_desc' => 'Price: High to Low',
                'release_date' => 'Release Date',
                'sales_popularity' => 'Bestselling',
                'rating_summary' => 'Top Rated',
                'reviews_count' => 'Most Reviewed',
            ];
        }
    
        public function getCurrentOrder()
        {
            $order = parent::getCurrentOrder();
    
            // The following prevents old URLs using name+direction or price+direction
            // from defaulting to relevance. It converts those old sorts into one of
            // the new sorts: name_asc, name_desc, price_asc, price_desc. 
            $orderParam = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getOrderVarName()));
            $dirParam = strtolower($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getDirectionVarName()));
            if (!in_array($dirParam, ['asc', 'desc'])) $dirParam = 'asc';
            if (!isset($orders[$orderParam])) {
                switch($orderParam) {
                    case 'name':
                        $order = "name_$dirParam";
                        break;
                    case 'price':
                        $order = "price_$dirParam";
                        break;
                }
            }
    
            // This forces the current sort to ALWAYS be memorized.
            // This is necessary for us because we force the sort order
            // to "relevance" whenever a search is performed by the
            // customer (hidden field on form.mini.phtml)
            //
            // The default behavior is to forget the sort when it is
            // set to "relevance" which then causes the next catalog
            // listing to default to whatever is set in the admin.
            // (unsSortOrder() in Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar)
            $this->_memorizeParam('sort_order', $order);
    
            $this->setData('_current_grid_order', $order);
            return $order;
        }
        
        /**
         * Set collection to pager
         *
         * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection
         * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
         */
        public function setCollection($collection)
        {
            parent::setCollection($collection);
    
            $order = $this->getCurrentOrder();
            switch($order) {
                case 'name':
                case 'name_asc':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'asc');
                    break;
    
                case 'name_desc':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('name', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'price':
                case 'price_asc':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'asc');
                    break;
    
                case 'price_desc':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('price', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'release_date':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('release_date', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'sales_popularity':
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('sales_popularity', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'rating_summary':
                    // Mage_Catalog_Model_Config controls which attributes can be used for sorting
                    // by eav_attribute for attributes that can be used for sortby.
                    // rating_summary is not in there since it's not a product attribute so this
                    // just adds the sort manually to the collection. jdw
                    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->join('review_entity_summary',
                        'review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value=e.entity_id and review_entity_summary.store_id=' . $storeId,
                        ['rating' => 'ceiling(rating_summary/10)', 'reviews_count'])->order(['rating desc', 'reviews_count desc']);
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('rating_summary', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'reviews_count':
                    // Mage_Catalog_Model_Config controls which attributes can be used for sorting
                    // by eav_attribute for attributes that can be used for sortby.
                    // rating_summary is not in there since it's not a product attribute so this
                    // just adds the sort manually to the collection. jdw
                    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                    $this->_collection->getSelect()->join('review_entity_summary',
                        'review_entity_summary.entity_pk_value=e.entity_id and review_entity_summary.store_id=' . $storeId,
                        ['rating_summary', 'reviews_count'])->order(['reviews_count desc']);
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('reviews_count', 'desc');
                    break;
    
                case 'default':
                default:
                    $this->_collection->setOrder('relevance', 'desc');
                    break;
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

is same i need use and for magento 2 shop, what i need to do, for displaying is same sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out this module:

https://www.sparsh-technologies.com/magento-extensions/magento-2-advanced-sorting-extension

it adds many options to sort products in toolbar, still if you want to have custom sorting then simply can download this one and get an idea of code to be written.